# RestKit not sending POST params

Tags: objective-c, restkit

Iam sending

```
[self.responseObjectManager.client post:@"" usingBlock:^(RKRequest * request){

    RKParams * params = [RKParams params];

    [params setValue:@"VALUE1" forParam:@"PARAM1"];

    request.params = params;

    request.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response){

        ALog(@"Loaded resp %@", response.bodyAsString);

    };

}];
```

index.php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo "WHAT IS ".$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']." ANOTHER".@file_get_contents('php://input');
echo "POST ".var_dump($_POST)." GET ".var_dump($_GET);
```

then i get back just

```
"Loaded resp POST  GET "
```

so it looks like the post params are not send

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in

```
[self.responseObjectManager.client post:@"" usingBlock:^(RKRequest * request){
```

had to specify directly index.php

```
[self.responseObjectManager.client post:@"/index.php" usingBlock:^(RKRequest * request){
```

than the response was vissible in

```
$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']
```